# Power of Chi-squared test in R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, statistical-power

I am trying to calculate the required sample size for my study. I found the `pwr`-package to be useful but cannot reproduce the results. What I did:

```
library(pwr)
prob <- matrix(c(0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8)/2, ncol=2, 
           dimnames = list(c("CRISPR","no CRIPSR"),c("No Alz","Alz")))
pwr.chisq.test(w = ES.w2(prob), df=(1), sig.level=0.05, power = 0.8)

> w = 0.7035265
> N = 15.8579
> df = 1
> sig.level = 0.05
> power = 0.8

> NOTE: N is the number of observations
```

Which is the same result that I got when using the free software G*Power, however the commercial software nQuery produced `N=14` (or 7 per group). Hence, I tried to reproduce the results by myself:

```
set.seed(112)
p1 = 0.9 
p2 = 0.2 
n = 6
n.reject = 0
n.rep = 10000
reject <- c(rep(NA, length(n.rep)))
for(k in 1:n.rep){ 
  x1 = sum(runif(n)<p1)
  x2 = sum(runif(n)<p2)
  ptest = prop.test( c(x1,x2), c(n,n), correct=F)
  reject[k] <- ifelse(ptest$p.value < 0.05, 1, 0)
}
sum(reject, na.rm = T)/n.rep
> 0.9219
```

The power here is more than I was aiming for. Setting `n=7`, the power is `0.8532`, with `n=6` it is `0.783`. Thus, the results regarding sample size are in line with nQuery. However, power is not the same, nQuery produces `82,796%` power for `n=7` per group.

Any idea where I am wrong?

Comment: This is a very small N, and in his 1988 book *Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences*, J. Cohen warns against the validity of conducting a chi-square test in such a situation (p. 268).  For a 2x2 tables with fixed margins and with the smallest expected value < 15, Kroonenberg & Verbeek recommend using an exact test instead (see https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00031305.2017.1286260, conclusion). Otherwise, maybe using simulation like you did is a good solution, given the large effect size you're interested in (where are 0.9 and 0.2 coming from, by the way?).